# Why does a profile 'redirect' url not work when 'html snippet' is used?

Tags: profile, snippet

Question says it all. The profile has a url redirect set in Advanced Settings. The outcome of submitting the profile from another site is that the user ends up on the profile url of the original site, and hence the URL redirect seems to be ignored - and no evidence of it having been including in the code of the html snippet.

Is it not included because it would be 'impossible' or just wasn't thought of?

Comment: Peter - did you get an answer to this? Are the HTML Snippets working at all, as far as you know?

Comment: i don't recall getting any resolution on this no.

Comment: but perhaps this offers an alternative? https://civicrm.org/blog/jamie/display-civicrm-forms-on-any-web-site-anywhere but not clear if it offers redirects